# Send Data from one activity to other activitry through Intent

Tags: php, android, android-intent, android-studio, android-imageview

// Data is not transfering to other activty and combine variable is not getting value under OnActivityResult() ca you tell me how to do it coz I need to pass the value of combine in Camera Activity

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener, ConnectionCallbacks {
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    GoogleSignInOptions gso;
    SignInButton signIn_btn;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    boolean loggedIn;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    ImageView camerat,galleryt;
    String combine;
    TelephonyManager tMgr;
    String name,email;
   // boolean b=true;
    ProgressDialog progress_dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.login);


      //  camerat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        //galleryt= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("APP", MODE_PRIVATE);
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLogin", false);
         name = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "");
         email = sharedPreferences.getString("e_mail", "");
         String ID = sharedPreferences.getString("ID", "");

        //  String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
        tMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        combine = name + "~" + tMgr.getLine1Number() + "~" + email;

        System.out.println("sss===" + name + email);

        if(loggedIn) {

             Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Camera.class);

            System.out.println("chokha " + name + combine);
            //Create the bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            //Add your data to bundle
            bundle.putString("combine_data", combine);
            //  bundle.putString("combine_data2",email);

            //Add the bundle to the intent
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            //Fire that second activity
            startActivity(i);

            finish();

        }

        else
        {

            buidNewGoogleApiClient();
            customizeSignBtn();
            setBtnClickListeners();
            progress_dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progress_dialog.setMessage("Signing in....");

            System.out.println("sss" + name + email);



        }


// oncreate ends here






    }

    /*
    Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile.
    User's ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    create and  initialize GoogleApiClient object to use Google  Sign-In API and the options specified by gso..
    */

    private void buidNewGoogleApiClient(){

        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this )
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
    }

    /*
      Customize sign-in button. The sign-in button can be displayed in
      multiple sizes and color schemes. It can also be contextually
      rendered based on the requested scopes. For example. a red button may
      be displayed when Google+ scopes are requested, but a white button
      may be displayed when only basic profile is requested. Try adding the
      Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN scope to see the  difference.
    */

    private void customizeSignBtn(){

        signIn_btn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signIn_btn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        signIn_btn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

    }

    /*
      Set on click Listeners on the sign-in sign-out and disconnect buttons
     */

    private void setBtnClickListeners(){
        // Button listeners
        signIn_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
      //  findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
       // findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }



    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "pita", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progress_dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(this, "chita", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }




            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            getSignInResult(result);

            /*System.out.println("Changu "+combine);
            GetSet o =new GetSet();
            o.setCombine(combine);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Camera.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();*/
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                progress_dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(this, "mitra", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                total();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                Toast.makeText(this, "start sign process", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gSignIn();
                break;

/*
            case R.id.sign_out_button:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google Sign Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gSignOut();
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Google Access Revoked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gRevokeAccess();
                break;*/

           /* case R.id.btn:

                camerat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Camera.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                });


                break;

            case R.id.btn2:

                camerat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Camera.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                });

                break;*/
        }
    }

    private void gSignIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        Toast.makeText(this, "zombie", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progress_dialog.show();




    }

    private void gSignOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                        updateUI(false);

                    }
                });



    }

    private void gRevokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                        updateUI(false);

                    }
                });
    }


    private void getSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {

        if (result.isSuccess()) {



            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            String id_token = acct.getIdToken(); //add this code here to save it by use SharedPreferences

          //  TextView user_name= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);
           // TextView email_id= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.emailId);
           // user_name.setText("UserName: "+ acct.getDisplayName());
            //email_id.setText("Email Id: " + acct.getEmail());
            updateUI(true);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("APP", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isLogin", true);

             editor.putString("name", acct.getDisplayName());
            editor.putString("e_mail", acct.getEmail());
            editor.putString("ID", acct.getIdToken());
            editor.commit();

            progress_dialog.dismiss();




        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }



    }


    private void updateUI(boolean signedIn) {
        if (signedIn) {
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
           findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       //     findViewById(R.id.btn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //    findViewById(R.id.btn2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
          //  findViewById(R.id.btn).setVisibility(View.GONE);
           // findViewById(R.id.btn2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

void total()
{

    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Camera.class);

    System.out.println("chokha " + name + combine);
    //Create the bundle
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    //Add your data to bundle
    bundle.putString("combine_data", combine);
    //  bundle.putString("combine_data2",email);

    //Add the bundle to the intent
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    //Fire that second activity
    startActivity(i);

    finish();
}

}
```

//Camera.java works fine

```
public class Camera extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://link.com/ImageUpload/upload.php";
    public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";
    public static final String UPLOAD_KEYS = "name";
    public static final String TAG = "MY MESSAGE";
    boolean b=false,m;
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    String mock;
    private Button buttonChoose;
    String uploadImage;
    private Button buttonUpload,buttonView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap bitmap,bitmaps;
    private Uri filePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);

        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

      buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonViewImage);

        buttonUpload.setEnabled(false);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);


       /* GetSet b= new GetSet();
        String maths=b.getCombine();
*/
    //    System.out.println("Matru "+maths);


        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        //Extract the data…
        String stuff = bundle.getString("combine_data");
        // String sss = bundle.getString("combine_data2");

        System.out.println("changa " + stuff);

        String[] max=stuff.split("~");

        for(int i=0;i<max.length;i++)
            System.out.println("binku " + max[i]);



    }


    private void selectImage() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


    }


    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if(b) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

                filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    buttonUpload.setEnabled(true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        else {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == 1) {
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                    for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                        if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                            f = temp;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    try {

                        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                        bitmaps = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                                bitmapOptions);

                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps);
                        buttonUpload.setEnabled(true);
                          mock= getStringImage(bitmaps);

                        String path = android.os.Environment
                                .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + File.separator
                                + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                        f.delete();
                        OutputStream outFile = null;
                        File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                        try {
                            outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                            outFile.flush();
                            outFile.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void uploadImage(){
        class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String>{

            ProgressDialog loading;
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(Camera.this, "Uploading Image", "Please wait...",true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
                buttonUpload.setEnabled(false);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
                Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
                if(b)
                uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);
                else
                    uploadImage = mock;
                HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
                data.put(UPLOAD_KEYS,"data1");

                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data);

                return result;

            }
        }

        UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
        ui.execute(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            b=true;
            m=true;
            showFileChooser();

        }
        if(v == buttonUpload){
            if(m) {
                uploadImage();
                m=false;
            }
                else

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Take photo or Choose photo first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // buttonUpload.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        if(v == buttonView){
            b=false;
            m=true;
            selectImage();

        }

    }
}
```

//Where should i place below code in Login.java so that I got my values and pass that values to other Activity

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Camera.class);

            System.out.println("chokha " + name + combine);
            //Create the bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            //Add your data to bundle
            bundle.putString("combine_data", combine);
            //  bundle.putString("combine_data2",email);

            //Add the bundle to the intent
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            //Fire that second activity
            startActivity(i);

            finish();
```

Comment: Where is the `combine` variable declared? Which data is the one that you want to pass?

Comment: First check is there any value in combine variable. try printing the value of combine variable.

Comment: @EricBrandwein  
see combine variable is under onActivityResult() and combine is declared in Login activity

Answer (score 0):

I think the method that you should be using is:

```
public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

Also, you don't have to call finish() on your original Activity after you start the next Activity.

You can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: forget finish() , think the code that I menitioned above separately , from that code combine is not getting value

Comment: Assuming that you want onActivityResult to be called in your Login Activity, in your Class Activity call the public final void setResult (int resultCode, Intent data) method and then call finish(). Otherwise you aren't passing a result back to the Login Activity anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding that data to intent itself ? Is that not working either?

Something like:

```
i.putExtra("name","John");
```

**EDIT**

In the second activity you`ll get that data like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String myName = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: What type of data you are trying to send ?

Comment: actually I want to send the combine value in combine variable under OnActivityResult , and the thing is that new activity is opening but data is not sending